# vlookup in a python list

Tags: python, pandas, list, vlookup

I have two dataframes:

[df1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EsoFc.png)

[df2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L3T6H.png)

The column items_list in df1 contains a list of items_id. What I want to do is create a new column ("domain_list") in df1 containing the corresponding list of domains_id for each of the items in the items_list according to the df2.

It's like a vlookup in excel.

Answer (score 0):

With the following dataframes as an example:

```
import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'item_id': [100,200,300], 'other': [1,2,3]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'item_id': [100,300], 'other2': ['one', 'three']})
```

**df1**:

```
    item_id other
0   100     1
1   200     2
2   300     3
```

**df2**:

```
    item_id other2
0   100     one
1   300     three
```

Now using `join`:

```
df1.join(df2.set_index('item_id'), on='item_id')

    item_id other   other2
0   100     1       one
1   200     2       NaN
2   300     3       three
```